# Error sumando meses a una fecha en un select con c#

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo una duda que creo que es un poco técnica. Necesito sumarle 6 meses a una variable que traigo por base de datos y ese resultado compararlo con una fecha.

Actualmente tengo una variable **dpOperaciones** que es de tipo *DataTable* en donde cargo toda mi información.

A esta le estoy realizando un select de esta forma:

```
rowFilasCondicion3 = dtOperaciones.Select("DATEADD(month,6,MINFEC) fecha < '"+ FechaUFPublica.ToString()+"'");
```

Esto me tira un error que dice "La expresión contiene una llama a la funcion sin definir DATEADD()"

Estoy usando como referencia estos links: [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y esta otra de [SqlServerTutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-dateadd-function/), pero también me encontré con algunas páginas que mencionan que es DATE_ADD el cual igual me arroja el error.

También, por el primer comentario, tengo otras consultas que funcionan que son las siguientes:

```
rowFilasCondicion1 = dtOperaciones.Select("MAXFECHA <> ultfechapago And FecMaxFuturos Is Null")

rowFilasCondicion2 = dtOperaciones.Select("TOO In ('09278','09279') And FecTrasp_Bch Is Null And FecTrasp_Cch Is Null")
```

El motor que estoy usando es SQL-Server

Adjunto una captura de la data que obtengo al pasar el mouse sobre la variable y desplegar lo que trae:
[image: captura]

¿Lo estoy implementando bien o me falta algo en rowFilasCondicion3?

Muchas Gracias

------------- EDITADO ---------

Al final si bien Jav me entrega una respuesta quizás un poco más completa, yo todavía no entiendo bien todo lo que se puede hacer con Linq, frente a esto me decidí por utilizar un ciclo for lo cual para mi es algo más simple de hacer y de entender.

Este es el código que utilicé para poder recorrer mi dtOperaciones, obtener la fecha, sumarle 6 meses y compararla con otra fecha. Son un poco más líneas pero para mi el resultado es más entendible para alguien que todavía no llega a cierto nivel utilizando C#:

```
int nCntCondicion3 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dtOperaciones.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   DateTime minfec = Convert.ToDateTime(dtOperaciones.Rows[i]["MINFEC"]);
   DateTime nuevaFecha = minfec.AddMonths(6);
   nCntCondicion3 = nuevaFecha < FechaUFPublica ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Necesitas especificar el motor de base de datos que estás utilizando. Si además estás utilizando un ORM, es posible que la sintaxis también cambie.

Comment: El motor está en sql, voy a poner otras consultas que tengo como ejemplo que si funcionan

Comment: Me causa ruido ese `SELECT`. Estas usando algún ORM para interactuar con la BD? Linq?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si, estoy usando Linq

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda, revisa la nueva respuesta q te puse, aunque hayas llegado a una esta puede serte util

Answer (score 0):

Realmente desconozco si las operaciones `Linq` se pueden implementar mediante *querys* propiamente tal, pero lo que podrías hacer es tomar la fecha a la que deseas agregarle los meses y usar el método **[AddMonths](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=net-5.0)** que viene con la clase **[DateTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0)**.

Entonces sería realizar

```
DateTime newDate = tuFecha.AddMonths(6);
```

Y después realizar el filtro mediante Where

```
var list = dtOperaciones.Where(x => x.fechaBD < newDate).ToList();
```

Ignoro el tipo de dato que es la fecha que obtienes desde BD, pero en caso que te devuelva un `string` por ejemplo ("2021-08-24"), debes **[castear](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)** o convertir el tipo hacia `DateTime` para que te funcione `AddMonths`.

Nos comentas si tienes alguna duda y/o si te sirvió.

Comment: adjunté una captura de como viene la data de mi variable dtOperaciones. no sé si me sirve tu método aunque entiendo lo que quieres hacer pero para el caso no sé si me serviría

Comment: al final lo implementé con un ciclo for, capturo la variable y le agregué los meses como lo indicas tú y ya después comparo con la fecha que necesito. Por algún motivo no me toma el DATEADD, pero llegué a una respuesta.

Comment: Excelente @SebastiánMiranda, considera incluir tu respuesta en la pregunta para futuros OP que tengan el mismo problema =)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando **Linq**:

```
var resultado = from r in dtOperaciones.AsEnumerable()
                let minFecha = r.Field<DateTime>("MINFEC")
                let fechaPublica = r.Field<DateTime>("FechaUFPublica")
                where minFecha.AddMonths(6) < fechaPublica
                select r;
```

En esta consulta **Linq** trabajamos el **DataTable** como si se tratase de un **IEnumerable**, de forma tal que podemos usar a C# para lograr nuestro objetivo.

Dentro de esta consulta usamos la **palabra clave let** para guardar en la variables de consulta **minFecha** y **fechaPublica** sus valores correspondientes por cada fila recorrida del **DataTable**.

Hecho esto entonces en la **clausula where** hacemos uso de estas variables para  filtrar por la condicion deseada:

```
minFecha.AddMonths(6) < fechaPublica
```

Usamos la **funcion AddMonths** propia de la clase **DateTime** de C# para aumentar en 6 los meses a la variable indicada y hacer la comparacion correspondiente.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: aplicando esta forma me arroja el mismo error, que llama a una función sin definir

Comment: Quitaste la palabra "fecha" como te dije?

Comment: si, lo dejé como string query = string.format("DATEADD(month, 6, MINFEC) < {0}", FechaUFPublica)

¿puede ser un problema con las librerias de sql que están en el proyecto? que no le guste el DATEADD

Comment: el MINFEC es una columna de la tabla de la base de datos, se ve al final de la captura. El FechaUFPublica es una fecha y tiene el formato DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda, revisa lo nuevo q puse